# How to speed of learning android programming by reducing redundant activities?

Tags: android, testing

I'm learning android. Fort testing every aspect of android SDK I need to create new project in eclipse and create new class and so on. I need a new way to decrease these redundant activities.

In Java programming I use groovy to learn Java faster, what about android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could put all your testing code in one project. Just create a new Activity in the same project. Then you can link activities together with a first page ListView. Take a look at API demos: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html (they are also in your android SDK under examples I think)
2. While you can use different JVM languages with Android, most of the examples are in Java, so IMHO this would be fastest way to learn.